# Google TTS on Android - voices over the network don't respect documentation

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

Since some recent update (possibly even the server side update) it appears that some Google TTS voices have a bug. It affects some (but not all) voices that use the network connection, e.g. it is reproducible on the voice en-us-x-tpc-network.

The problem is that they do not react to the [setSpeechRate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#setSpeechRate(float)) API properly - for them the lower value than 1 speed up the speech above normal and higher value than 1 slow down the speech below normal.

Is someone familiar with this bug and does have some recommendation? If it is not submitted, where is the proper place to submit this to Google?

Comment: We experience the same problem and it's being the real pain, but I couldn't find any solution as well.

Comment: btw, left the issue about this problem in Google IssueTracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188433823

Comment: @GregoryYanushkovskiy I've already submitted the issue in another Google's box a month ago...

Comment: Oh, could you share the link, please? Maybe in this case they will answer your one first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed with the latest update by Google.